# Does stackoverflow.com-Posts.7 in March 2017 Stack Exchange data dump contain posts from Jan-Mar'17?

Tags: support, data-dump

The md5sums of stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z files in Mar'17 Stack Exchange data dump and Dec'16 Stack Exchange data dump are identical (776cab94cd0c2244a9dbe3047e74decc).  The files are of the same size as well (34857919 lines).  So, it seems they are identical.  Is it true?  If so, can Stack Exchange team please upload the updated stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z file for Mar'17 data dump?

Comment: SHAttered??????

Comment: Given the same number of lines and same unpacked file sizes, I doubt if we are observing SHA collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it I think it does. I haven't downloaded the files to confirm, but the torrent metadata doesn't match your observation.

The March 2017 release (with BitTorrent infohash `586eebe6f3c19db48a5ea471579b96d3bd3ba6e3`) includes the following metadata for that file:

```
{
  "crc32": "60771106",
  "length": 10790576915,
  "md5": "776cab94cd0c2244a9dbe3047e74decc",
  "mtime": "1489559143",
  "path": [
    "stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z"
  ],
  "sha1": "34202070af1eeb7b8234d118f78ce42973d74037"
}
```

The December 2016 release (with BitTorrent infohash `fd86cb81c9ab08bd3a0969d4c700555ec7814328`) includes the following metadata for that file:

```
{
  "crc32": "a914a67d",
  "length": 10320191802,
  "md5": "ba6d673604e2b53b4e194ddb206561c5",
  "mtime": "1481831889",
  "path": [
    "stackoverflow.com-Posts.7z"
  ],
  "sha1": "b50bf3064ef0fd5c93224005202ec6b7b2d921a5"
}
```

You can see that the March 2017 release is larger, has a later timestamp, and has different hashes.

(The per-file hashes/checksums aren't enforced by the BitTorrent protocol, so those could hypothetically be wrong. However, the file sizes (`length`) are fundamental and must be correct for the torrent to function.)

Comment: I just checked the contents of Posts.xml and I found some posts from Mar'17 towards the end of the file.  So, I think you are right.  Phew!  I guess some copying issues at my end :)